# Can an iOS native interface use NSData (byte[]) as a parameter or return value?

Tags: codenameone

Edit: As per the answer below, the answer is YES, it can

I tried looking through the docs but didn't find any reference to this

I tried building but there always is an error whenever the return value or a param in a native interface is `NSData` (`byte[]`)

Is it not supported? Thx

For example, the following interfaces blow:

```
- (NSData*)someMethod{
}

- (void)someMethod:(NSData*)param{
}
```

The server error file never mentions any specific error when an error occurs in a native interface class so I am asking here for clarity/reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the return value but the parameter should work and is documented in `Listing 22. NativeInterface definition` in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html) as:

```
public void test(byte b, boolean boo, char c, short s,
    int i, long l, float f, double d, String ss,
    byte[] ba, boolean[] booa, char[] ca, short[] sa, int[] ia,
    long[] la, float[] fa, double[] da,
    PeerComponent cmp);
```

Which generates:

```
-(void)test:(char)param param1:(BOOL)param1
    param2:(int)param2 param3:(short)param3 param4:(int)param4
    param5:(long long)param5 param6:(float)param6
    param7:(double)param7 param8:(NSString*)param8
    param9:(NSData*)param9 param10:(NSData*)param10
    param11:(NSData*)param11 param12:(NSData*)param12
    param13:(NSData*)param13 param14:(NSData*)param14
    param15:(NSData*)param15 param16:(NSData*)param16
    param17:(void*)param17;
}
```

If you're getting an error we'll need the link for the full error log as well as the applicable native interface code.

Comment: build server logs are very limited for ios native interfaces. Basically it just shows the name of the file:
`The following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Volumes/MacintoshHD2/temp/build6072804674150915771xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GroupChart/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GroupChart.build/Release-iphoneos/GroupChart.build/Objects-normal/armv7/native_com_groups_interfaces_GroupsNativeInterfacesImplCodenameOne...
`

Comment: Seems the developer's guide table is wrong by a column. There is one too many?

Comment: We use byte[] in cn1libs e.g. https://github.com/shannah/CN1Sockets/blob/master/src/ca/weblite/codename1/net/impl/NativeSocket.java I'll still need the build error. Sometimes the error is in a different location in the file.

Comment: I don't know why for the longest time I haven't been able to do this, but today I tried again and it worked. It probably helps knowing how to read iOS build server logs... I always thought the only important part were the lines near the end. Thank you so much for this